# How do I change the hostname in InfoPath Form data connection?

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I've created a InfoPath form which uses Data Connections. This was on server1.

Now I want to change this InfoPath Form on server2 (server1 does not exist anymore). I want to add a new Data Connection.

I do use the Connection Options as Local Connection library, so the link to the data connection file is relative.

When I look into the Data Connections for the form template, I still see the Connection Source beeing the server1. When I add a new connection, the Source is server2.

When I Preview the Form, the Form still tries to connect server1 !

How can I change this ?

I found a way to do this: [Manually editing data connection details in InfoPath 2007 forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/hakaneren/archive/2009/05/04/manually-editing-data-connection-details-in-infopath-2007-forms.aspx). For me, only the save as source files worked.

Is this the best way to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as far I'm aware that's the only way.

You need to save the source files out in InfoPath client, edit the manifest file with the correct URLs, then save and publish back into SharePoint.

I haven't come across any community tools that make this process easier but you would think there's a good need for them. You may want to search around for that.

Comment: Agreed. The only way is to a) save as source files b) edit manifest.xsf (this is the only place where your site will be referenced) and then c) republish the form. While the .udcx files can be stored in a data connection library, where that site is gets written into the manifest file. Stupid Microsoft. Same thing with GUIDs being embedded into udcx files which makes centralizing them ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few projects since I've done Infopath, but are we talking about connections stored externally to the form? These are stored in a .udcx file in a Data Connection Library. If so, why isn't it as simple as just editing the .udcx file? If not, why store embed the connection in the form rather than use .udcx files?

Or am I missing something altogether?

Comment: It's about the location of the udcx file. The form was edited for server1, and now I want to add a new udcx file. The location of the udcx file is stored in the xsn (manifest)

Comment: Gotcha. For doing anything more than editing existing entries in an existing .udcx file, I'd agree the form needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here are related more detailed posts published later on how to do the same:

- [How to reconnect InfoPath task form to SPD workflow after moving it to the new Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s)
- [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)

I post it only to relate posts which before this my post were not related/linked through links in Related section, on right side.