# publish infopath listform to sharepoint multiple site's list

Tags: infopath, custom-form, forms-services

I have one site collection that having two subwebs: i.e web1,web2

both webs having one `Test` custom list.i have open `Test` list and using `Customize Form` tab into list setting of Ribbon.

than i publish infopath form to this list.again doing same operation into web2's `Test` list.

can we directly use web1's list infopath form to web2's list. I mean i dont want to every time open infopath form and republish in each of subwebs lists.

Anytime to changing in design of info-path form than every time open infopath form changing and republish to every sub-webs's list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to publish "Sharepoint List Form" compatibility/type Infopath template to more than one list

You can "centralize" and automatize (make a script at Windows level to a manual procedure I gave below) to restricting changes just to one template (in Infopath Designer 2010), and after making changes in one, to "replicate" the template's copy (or copies) adjusting them to a different publishing location, see answers to [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/27811/8319) question:

- save template locally also under another name (make copy of template) > export source files, change all enclosed URLs in manifest.xsf (and probably view*.xsl) file(s) in XML editor > open and (save+) publish adjusted for another publishing site/location copy of template

Update:
Upon making changes in order to republish you should open manifest.xsf in Infopath Designer 2010.

For this, open it by right-clicking in Windows Explorer on it and choosing **Design**.
Otherwise, open Infopath Designer 2010 and on ribbom navigate **File** > **Open** > navigate to directory with manifest.xsf

[image]

This is not straightforward procedure. One should make the procedures manually first comparing the exported source files.

You will also need the ListID of the list which you can find by righ-clicking on, for example, **Add new item** link and finding/replacing sharePointListID in exported files.

I re-asked this question in infopathdev.com in thread:

- [How do I move infopath from Dev to QC or Production](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/21923/81104.aspx#81104)

where the qualified Infopath professionals answer

Comment: i have doing all the changes..but i dont know how to publish that Export source files.`i did googling and found like :  Right click on the manifest.xsf file and go to Design.Quick Publish back to the server`but m not able to see Design option on right click of manifest.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now trying to elaborate with more specific descriptions