# Change SharePoint List an Infopath form posts

Tags: infopath, form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)

I'm using Infopath and Sharepoint 2010. I created a form that posts to a specific SharePoint list. I saved the Infopath from to my desktop and published it to SharePoint, everything works. There's the thing, I need to create more forms very similiar to the one I created that publish to different lists. Is there a way to change the List the form posts to? I spent at least 20 minutes searching Google and within InfoPath without luck.