# Unable to modify input and output locations after migration an InfoPath 2007 form to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, infopath, migration

First of all, I’m not expert with InfoPath but I have several years of experience with SharePoint 2010. This means I’m not newbie but I feel completely insecure working with InfoPath.

I am trying to migrate an InfoPath form from an old SharePoint 2007 server to SharePoint 2010. Somehow, I successfully changed the publish location by modifying manually the manifest.xsf and the view.xsl files as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location).

The form is taking the input data from a txt file located in a Document Library at the SharePoint 2007 server, let’s say

> http://sharepoint2007.com/Data/Data_IN/

and saving the result also as txt at

> http://sharepoint2007.com/Data/Data_OUT/

which is also a document library.

Well, my form is working properly in SharePoint 2010 after the migration but it’s still taking the input parameters from the old SharePoint 2007 server and saving the output result also in the SharePoint 2007 server.

After checking every single file encapsulated in the xsn template file, I cannot find the references to this two Document Libraries. Neither can I find any reference to this txt files using InfoPath Designer 2010.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the problem. After the migration to SharePoint 2010 the Web Services were also migrated as they were, with old references to to the SharePoint 2007 site. I didn know at the time I wrote this question, but the InfoPath form was relying entirly on this web services, where all the code behind was executed.

After re-building the web services with the correct path, the form was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a form that has been published to a form library. This based on what you describe above. There are a couple of things I would check. First, have you verified all the data connections? Not saying this is the answer, but it might help. Another option, is that there is code attached to the form. Either C# or Visual Basic. You would have to expose the developer tab to get to this section, but most often this is where you will find what is doing the work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By checking the data connections, do you mean the .udcx files? If yes, I've checked them. No reference there (but I'll double check). All the controls related with Development Tools in InfoPath are greyed out. Could it be because I don't have Visual Studio installed in the server?

Comment: Not exactly, but you don't have to go through the files manually for data connections. There is a Data tab in the top and there is a Data Connections button. In that popup should be all the defined connections. And so also, the Developer tab options are greyed out you say? I believe VSTA is involved there, and yes, you might have to have Visual Studio for that. I do so I am not 100% sure on that.