# Restore Content Database on different Farm with InfoPath Forms

Tags: infopath, migration, content-database, restore, forms-services

We have an activity to backup a content database from SharePoint 2013 server and restore it on a different SharePoint 2013 Farm. The Database contains many InfoPath forms. Yes, the URL will be changed.

1. Would the InfoPath forms will start working seamlessly or they all will have to be individually opened and published again one by one?
2. If the answer to above question is publish each form again. Do we have to follow same steps in case we are not migrating but just changing the default URL of the web application on the same Farm?

Comment: Have you done with restore content database

Answer (score 0):

**Would the InfoPath forms will start working seamlessly or they all will have to be individually opened and published again one by one?**

You will need to open your form again , update the URL and data connections as the following

- From Publish> Clcik on `export source files` > then opened `manifest.xsf` and `view*.xsl` in a text editor and replaced all URLs (`siteURL` and `sharePointListID`)  with the new one.

[image]

- Publish it again .

**If the answer to above question is publish each form again. Do we have to follow same steps in case we are not migrating but just changing the default URL of the web application on the same Farm?**

As a short answer yes , this is because of the published URL / sharePointListID  is changed to the new web application , so you need to update your data connection and the published URL as I mentioed above.

For more details check [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps you have to perfrom, even these are from SP 2010 but still valid for 2013.

- First Test Content Database:
- Export Infopath form:
- Import Infopath:
- Update url of Infopath admin approved form:
- Update url of user input infopath forms:
- Run the following commands to force deactivating and activating the
  Forms Services feature:

[Update InfoPath forms after content DB restore to different URL in SharePoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25143.update-infopath-forms-after-content-db-restore-to-different-url-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Form Library using SharePoint Designer
2. Export template.xsn file on local machine
3. Open that template.xsn file from Info-path form designer
4. Replace all data connection.
5. Publish to server.

Now when you have create new form it will show all data in form. means if you have any look value. drop down list haveing data comeing from list.

If your Info Path form library contains existing documents. to point that document link to current site. that time you have to Relink Documents

[image]