# How to copy an infopath form 2010 to a new location so I can modify and test?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have been tasked to modify an InfoPath 2010 form.
I need to copy it , modify it with proposed changes and then upload it to a different area so that it does not touch the original form's data. ( A new , clean data area would be fine ).

I have a copy of it downloaded to my desktop. But how do I change where it is published to and what steps do I need to take to point the form to write elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open the Template copy via InfoPath.
- From Publish> Clcik on `export source files` > then opened `manifest.xsf` and `view*.xsl` in a text editor and replaced all URLs (`siteURL` and `sharePointListID`)  with the new one.

[image]

- Save the manifest.xsf.
- Right Click on it and select Design.
- Go to file > Publish > the URL Should be now changed.
- Click Publish.

For other Methods check [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)

Comment: Have I told you I love you lately? :) 
You're definitely a sort of Angel. Thank you!

Comment: you need to change also **contentTypeID** in a `manifest.xsf file`. see details https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/55553/41330