# Rename library url effects on workflows, forms

Tags: workflow, url, library, rename

I know how to rename a list or library URL in SharePoint Designer 2010, but how will this affect workflows and InfoPath forms associated with the list?  Will I need to go through all forms and workflows to update URLs?

Is there a way to rename the URL and automatically update workflows and forms?

I need to rename it because the original creator gave it a cumbersome name (52 characters and full of spaces), and we are having problems due to the length of the library name + the document name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the workflow, SharePoint will automatically update that information for you.

InfoPath is a little trickier.  You could open your files within a text editor (e.g. Visual Studio) and update the publishing URLs.

Or you can:

1. You can save as your existing list as template.
2. At same site or different site, create new list using saved form
   template.
3. Then go to New List - List Settings -> General Settings -> Form
   Settings.
4. Select modify the existing Info Path Form
5. Click button OK

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)