# How to publish SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am rather new to SharePoint and InfoPath.  I have two Sharepoint Lists, SLC Test and SLC Test 2.  I have an InfoPath program SLC Test that is published to SLC Test.  How do I get the program to publish to SLC Test 2?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can republish the form to a different library if the infopath form was created for SharePoint Form library by going to File->Publish->Sharepoint Server and going through the steps. But if it is for a SharePoint list I don't think it is possible to republish but you can template the list and create another list from that template.Please also be considerate about the data connections on the form if your lists are in different site collections. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can not do this anyway in InfoPath Designer.

You need to update this URL manually by updating the manifest.xsf file of the InfoPath form. For more detailed information, refer to the following article:

https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/deploying-infopath-form-to-a-list-in-a-different-site-in-sharepoint/

Alternatively you can save the list "SLC Test" as list template and create a new list based this tepmlate. The new list will automatically has the InfoPath form.

More reference:

[Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)