# Parent site URL changed, form broken, just republish?

Tags: infopath

I have a couple of InfoPath library forms (not list forms) hosted under let's say Site B, where site B is a subsite of Site A. I recently changed the URL of site A and all forms are broken.

I attempted to fix this simply by opening up the .XSN file in infopath, FILE >>> Publish >>>> SharePoint Server >>>

Here I found that the URL was the old URL of site A before the change, so I updated it to the new URL of site A. Hit Next, Next, and instead of creating a new form library, I simply choose Update the form template in an existing library, and pick the same library.

Voila! the form is back to normal again.

Now my questions: If it is this simple, why there are posts out there saying something like saving a local copy of the XSN file, exporting its source, and changing the URL within the .manifest file (some even say it needs to be converted to .CAB file) [like here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4aabacd6-7d6d-4778-8bd2-b4620ea717db/change-the-target-site-list-url-for-publishing-infopath-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)? Or some even say, some file called .udcx file need to be modified [like here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location)? All these suggestions make me think if it is this complicated, I might have done something wrong?

Or is it because these complicated steps are meant for Infopath list forms only instead of library forms? Or they have to do with opening up old .XML records? (My forms in question only use emailing to send out responses and do not save a XML record in the form library)

So just would like to confirm that these complicated steps (changing .manifest file/.udcx file) doesn't apply to my case? Please advise!

Environment: SharePoint 2013 on-premise. InfoPath 2013

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath development environment is quite complex. According to my past experience in InfoPath, there are multiple parts related to path change:

1. URL of form library (which you have updated)
2. Data Connection files (which normally saved within your data connection library)
3. Code behind
4. external data sources

Also, depends on what kind of URL change is involved. In your case you are moving forms within the same site collection which is relative simple. It is because your data connection library, related lists & libraries, content types etc would be the same after moved. It would be more complicated when you moved across site collections or across farm.

By checking the .manifest and .udcx files you can review what are the original paths. Some developer use full path and some use relative paths.

In some situation, the ex-developer do not keep the source code when he/she left the company. Sometimes the ex-developer hardcoded the path in the code. You need to export the source files in order to revise the code. Also, the InfoPath form need to bind with its source code, compile and publish, and deploy as a new farm solution.

I am not expert of InfoPath and not work to its technology any more. Hope other experts will also comment to this thread.